# RabbitMQ driver for Laravel Queue Class Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, rabbitmq

I am using https://github.com/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq

After running composer install successfully and updating app.php it throws following error. I have made sure that configs are correct. I am using Laravel 5.1

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]

Class 'VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\LaravelQueueRabbitMQServiceProvider' not found
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there was some issue in the 5.1 tag itself. I raised on issue with creator. Here is the link to ticket https://github.com/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq/issues/46

After few days https://github.com/vladimir-yuldashev/ (the author) replied and I took the update. Issue was gone.

Thanks to package author. All credit goes to him.

Answer (score 0):

After composer update is finished you need to add ServiceProvider to your providers array in app.php:

VladimirYuldashev\LaravelQueueRabbitMQ\LaravelQueueRabbitMQServiceProvider::class

([vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq](https://github.com/vladimir-yuldashev/laravel-queue-rabbitmq))